# Powershell certificate scripting using HttpClient

Tags: .net, powershell

I am looking to use powershell to get certificate information from different API's using HttpClient. (Trying to write a script to find when certificates expire). I am so new to powershell and don't know where to start. From research I was trying the code below, but when using [Net.HttpWebRequest] it brings back a null for certificate when looking at $req.ServicePoint.Certificate. From [https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29301] this resource it looks like HttpWebRequest is outdated. Any suggestions on retrieving certificate information using powershell??

```
$timeoutMs = 10000
$sites = @("https://testsite1.com/")


Write-Host Checking $sites -f Green
$req = [Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($sites)
$expDate = $req.ServicePoint.Certificate.GetExpirationDateString()
```

Comment: the create() method just creates an instance of an HttpWebRequest.  You need to actually execute the request with one of the methods available (e.g. GetResponse(), etc.).  Also, the create() method only takes a single string, not an array of values (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.create?view=net-5.0).  Also, according to the HttpWebRequest class's newest documentation, you should use System.Net.Http.HttpClient instead of HttpWebRequest:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=net-5.0

Comment: [Does this help?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-website-ssl-certificate-validity-dates-with-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

You can use TcpClient in dotnet core.

```
$hostname = 'www.google.com'
$ExpirationDays = 90
$request = [System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient]::new($hostname, '443')
$stream = [System.Net.Security.SslStream]::new($request.GetStream())
$stream.AuthenticateAsClient($hostname)
$effectiveDate = $stream.RemoteCertificate.GetEffectiveDateString() -as [datetime]
$expirationDate = $stream.RemoteCertificate.GetExpirationDateString() -as [datetime]
if ($expirationDate -lt [datetime]::UtcNow.AddDays($ExpirationDays)) {
    Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=warning] Update certificate for [$hostname]"
    $expiringObjectList += [pscustomobject] @{
        Hostname       = $stream.TargetHostName
        Thumbprint     = $stream.RemoteCertificate.Thumbprint
        Start          = [string]$effectiveDate
        End            = [string]$expirationDate
        ExpirationDays = (New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date) -End $expirationDate).Days
    }
}
```