# Get SSL certificate of a webserver using URL in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, ssl, automation, window

I'm trying to get the ssl certificate of a web server, this below code is working fine on windows 2019 server and 2022, but when ran on 2016 server it's not working the following code is returning null in place of certificate.

`$webRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create("https:/www.google.com") try { $webRequest.GetResponse() } catch {} $cert = $webRequest.ServicePoint.Certificate`

the $cert value is null (windows server 2016)

after some research i found out that have to use HttpClient instead of WebRequest, but don't know how to use it, please help me out here.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69487704/powershell-certificate-scripting-using-httpclient

Comment: tried that too,  giving me this error
Exception calling "AuthenticateAsClient" with "1" argument(s): "A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception."

Comment: TLS is probably failing on older server.  It is probably the server not bein updated to support TLS.